# How can I export the names from struct to an excel file?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to export a struct

```
'bc26bi5010conus.tif'   49028417    false   736617.740439815    '14-Oct-2016 17:46:14'
'bc26bi501conus.tif'    49028417    false   736617.740393519    '14-Oct-2016 17:46:10'
'bc26bi502conus.tif'    49028417    false   736617.740451389    '14-Oct-2016 17:46:15'
```

I want to export the names(First column) into an excel sheet.

How can I do this? I have tried 3 things:

```
xlswrite('test.xls', allFiles)
Error using xlswrite (line 165)
Input data must be a numeric, cell, or logical array.
```

2nd:

```
xlswrite('test.xls', allFiles.name)
    Error using xlswrite (line 206)
    Invalid data range: BC26BI502CONUS.TIF.
```

Finally,

```
for i = 1:length(allFiles) 
        tempData{i} = allFiles(i).name;
        dlmwrite('headers.csv', tempData{i}, '-append')
end
```

This is putting the letters of the filenames in separate cells. (e.g. b c   2   6   b   i   5   0   1   0   c .....)

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

```
fid = fopen('a.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s \n', allFiles.name);
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were close with your `for` loop and `fprintf`.

```
fid = fopen('headers.csv','wt');

for i = 1:length(allFiles) 
        tempData = allFiles(i).name;
        fprintf(fid, '%s \n', tempData);
end

fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `allFiles.name` is a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). It should be converted to a cell array:

```
xlswrite('test.xls', {allFiles.name})
```